# compare values in two arrays with a margin of variance

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Good afternoon guys, I'm reading about the setdiff1d function of numpy library on python:
(https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html).

Its serve basically to express the different values between 2 arrays, e.g. (from the link above):

```
>>> a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 1])
>>> b = np.array([3, 4, 5, 6])
>>> np.setdiff1d(a, b)
array([1, 2])
```

I'm wondering if exists any function that allows inserting a percentage of variation in the compared values.

Explanation: as well as shown in the example, the function setdiff1d will return the values that are exactly different between 2 arrays.

But, if I'm working with floats, and I want to allow a percentage of these values, for example, to considerer 3.35 equals to 3.34, there is any specific function that works with this situation, where I can set as an argument one variation margin between the compared values?

Best,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
def get_difference(va, vb, margin=0):
    return [a for a in set(va) if not
        all(a < (b - margin) or a > (b + margin)
        for b in set(vb))]
```